# How to propose myself to a different, more senior, position in the organization, 5 months after I joined it

Tags: job-change

So I joined a company about 5 months ago to position A.

It is a big company (1000+ employees).

The company has posted a new position ("position B"), in a different department, that is more senior than my current position.

I have some experience that is relevant to position B and I think it may fit me better than the current position I fill.

I wonder if and how it is possible to apply to position B.

Cons

- Suggesting such a thing will raise questions about my fit to the
  current role. My manager may don't like it and may wish to find a
  different person to fill my position, regardless if I move to
  position B.

Pro

- I feel some frustration in position A and think position B may be better for me for the long run and in terms of career path

Following some questions from comments:

- Yes, people are fired from the company and it is not hard to fire people.
- Inquiring about position B with HR or the relevant manager will obviously expose me.

Is this a catch-22 with no real solution?

Comment: Please provide some additional info about your country and the size of the company. Is it pretty common that people get fired in your company? In some big companies of some countries getting fired is very hard and you don't have much risk in applying.

Comment: @nicola the company is big (1000+). Yes, people are fired from the company and it is not hard to fire people.

Comment: Edit the question to include all the relevant information.

Comment: Why not ask your boss/hr about this? Seems that they are the ones who will know internal application track.

Comment: If you make discrete enquires about position B will your boss find out?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that this varies by country, and certainly varies by company, but often, when you are hired, your boss puts in time and energy getting you trained for the job they need done.  If you try to leave that job before they've even got their money's worth, you burn bridges, even if it's at the same company.  They then have to hire again, because the job still needs to be done.

A common standard I've heard for the US, is stay in a job at least 1 year before trying to transfer.  I've had jobs that explicitly say that - you're not allowed to transfer until you've worked at a company for a year.

So, you need to balance your desires for that job with the bridges you'll be burning, and probably not just with your boss.  In fact, probably the only way to not burn a bridge is if your current job is one where you are easily replaceable, the company would find it more difficult to fill the other job, and probably if you talk to your boss first, to see what they think.  If your boss is not someone safe to talk to (and many are not), you're taking a chance.  Even applying may hurt your long-term chances at this company.

If these types of jobs don't open very often, and you are very qualified, it still might be worth it.  If the company is often hiring, and you might expect a similar position to open in a year or two, it would be safer to stay where you are, show yourself to be a stellar and valuable employee, and the next time, you'll be a known good quantity who has already made the company money.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if and how it is possible to apply to position B.

Presumably the internal job posting made this clear, whether it's an email to HR or a formal application in an ATS platform.

In other words, you are overthinking this.

### If it's a good fit, apply to the role.

**Problem**: Your manager might seek to replace you if you don't win the position

**Answer**: If you work for this type of manager, this is even more reason to want to change positions. Decent managers want to see their reports succeed within the organization.

**Problem**: Applying to another position might raise questions about your fit in your current role

**Answer**: No, it won't. If you're not a good fit in your current role, that's entirely separate, and probably not a secret.

Assuming what you've said is true (you have relevant experience, would be a good fit, and overall would make a qualified candidate for position B), there just are no relevant downsides to applying for it.